# PDF Submit a Form Button Safari

Tags: pdf, safari, adobe

I made a .pdf with a Save Document button with the following attributes in Adobe Acrobat:

- Submit a Form
- Entered a URL: Tested local and remote URLs
- Export Format: HTML

It works fine in Opera, Chrome, Firefox, IE(6,7,8,9) but not Safari. It is using the Adobe Reader plug-in; not the native reader that Safari has.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Adobe again, and their technical support was more helpful.

It is a known issue, and Adobe suggests using a different browser, or downgrade to Safari 5.0.1.

Adobe will soon issue a patch for this to work with Safari 5.1.1.